# Update 20.04.01 to 20.04.02 and this version its slow

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates, video, multimedia

Upgrade 20.04.01 to 20.04.02, I start a call (google-meet, zoom, microsoft teams), I can not do anything behind because it is very slow, another case, I start youtube or twitch in google chrome, I notice a slow software behind.

On 20.04.01 I did not notice this, what is happening?

I attached this link, he talk on 20.04.02.0 but is not my version bug:
[Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 hotfix released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-February/000265.html)

Comment: What is your Logs saying? `/var/log`

Comment: Hi, sorry but, i dont know system it slow. I was reset PC and I installing other linux.